# Writing utf-8 to file but parsing incorrectly

Tags: python, utf-8

I am reading in text (stored as paper_dict['Abstract']) from a website that is encoded in utf-8 and trying to write it out to a utf-8 encoded file.

But the ' (apostrophe) character is coming out as â or Ã¢ÂÂ instead. If I manually encode the text as utf-8 then it is shown as \xe2\x80\x99 or \xc3\xa2\xc2\x80\xc2\x99.

I keep getting this same issue, regardless of the method I've tried using to write the text to a file. Here is one example:

```
import io
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

f = io.open('file.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='a+')
base = 'https://www.federalreserve.gov'
path = '/econres/notes/feds-notes/index.htm'
response = requests.get(base + path, verify=False)
page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
links = page.find_all('a', href=re.compile("/econres/notes/feds-notes/"))
for a in links:
    paper_dict = {}
    paper_dict['Abstract'] = a.find_next('p').find_next('p').text
    print(paper_dict['Abstract'], file=f)
```

or

```
f.write(paper_dict['Abstract'])
```

The particular example I've been looking at is the note titled "SOMA's Unrealized Loss: What does it mean?" which has a description of "This Note discusses the various valuation measures of the Fed’s securities holdings, what these values mean, and the expected evolution of the value of the SOMA portfolio." But in my output file, instead of "Fed's" it says "Fedâs"

Comment: What's the value of `text`? We need a [mcve].

Comment: `ecoding='utf-8'` This is obviously not your real code, as `encoding` is misspelled.  Please post your actual, real code.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your file contains the correct UTF-8 encoded strings. The problems probably comes from the fact that you later read it as if it was latin1 (iso-8859-1) encoded.

And you should be cautious that the APOSTROPHE (`'`) is the unicode character U+0027, or the ASCII character of code 0x27, but in the HTML page you get, `Fed’s` contains a different character, a RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK which is the unicode character U+2019.

Now everything can be explained:

`"Fed’s".encode('utf8')` is the following byte string: `b'Fed\xe2\x80\x99s'`. If you try to read (decode) it as latin1, you get:

```
>>> "Fed’s".encode('utf8').decode('latin1')
'Fedâ\x80\x99s'
```

because `â` is the unicode character U+00E2 or the iso-8859-1 character of code 0xe2. And in the Latin1 character set, both `'\x80'` and `'\x99'` are non printing characters, so you get:

```
>>> print("Fed’s".encode('utf8').decode('latin1'))
Fedâs
```

So your output file is correct, simply the way you display it is wrong: you should use an UTF-8 enable text editor, like the excellent vim (gvim) or notepad++ (google for them if you do not know them).

Comment: Thank you, sounds like I'm almost there! But I tried opening the output file in Microsoft Word, choosing utf-8 as the encoding to read it, and it still displays the text as Fedâ and then two boxes and then s.

Comment: Microsoft Word is not what I would call an UTF-8 enabled text editor.

Comment: Even when I use VIM and read it with utf-8 encoding (:edit ++enc=utf-8 file.txt), it still shows Fedâ and two boxes...

Comment: @JZ115: I am thinking about the `'\xc3\xa2\xc2\x80\xc2\x99'` which is twice encoding... Vim normally allows to convert the text in hexadecimal (don't save in that mode!). Could you tell me how exactly the right quote is encoded in hexa?

Comment: Yeah it looks like that is how it is encoded when I view the hexa in VIM. Is there a way to resolve the issue in that case?

Comment: @JZ115 I have just controlled and the original HTML page is correct. Could you control what is the encoding used by requests? Specifically what does `print(response.encoding)` display?